# Embedding googleVis charts into a web site

Tags: r, google-visualization

Reading from the [googleVis](http://code.google.com/p/google-motion-charts-with-r/) package [vignette](http://google-motion-charts-with-r.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inst/doc/googleVis.pdf): *"With the googleVis package users can create easily web pages with interactive charts based on R data frames and display them either via the R.rsp package **or within their own sites**"*. Following the instructions I was able to see the sample charts, using the [plot](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/googleVis/html/gvisMethods.html) method for gvis objects. This method by default creates a rsp-file in the rsp/myAnalysis folder of the googleVis package, using the type and chart id information of the object and displays the output using the local web server of the R.rsp package (port 8074 by default).

Could anybody help me (or provide some link) on the procedure someone has to follow in order to embed such charts into an existing web site (e.g. a joomla site)?

Comment: If you have a web server, then rename .rsp to .html, then upload it on your server, and access via http:// . probably it works. So, if joomla supports <scirpt> tag, then copying the contents of .rsp would work. Sorry for that I'm unfamiliar with the joomla. Although I cannot publish since I cannot use <script> in my wordpress site, it (rename and upload) is working on my private web site.

Comment: It didn't for me. It seems that is working only through the HTTP daemon that preprocesses R Server Pages and only accepts connections from the local host. What is more, The MotionChart rsp file, for example, contains some lines like <%@include file="../src/simpleHead.rsp"%>. How will it access those files (with relative paths) after copying and pasting?

Comment: Hi, hmm..., it is working for me... The @include directive has nothing to do with chart generation. so, if you access the motionchart .html via, eg., apache, then the directives themselves appears on the page, but the chart still works. All we need to generate chart are from <script> to <div> in the .rsp. So, you can use these part of code inside your own webpage.

Comment: In other words, M1$html$chart, where M1 <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year"), seems to be enough to generate google chart. If someone know the place where I can put html with <script> tag, I will show examples :-(

Comment: finally I found that blogger supports <script> tag, so here is an example: http://takahashik.blogspot.com/2011/01/googlevis-example.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Obviously I think that this is too verbose for @gd047, but I put a kind of tutorial since it maybe helpful for other readers who want to use googleVis on their own website.

install googleVis from CRAN

```
install.packages('googleVis')
```

pay attention to the messages.

then, create gvis object:

```
library(googleVis)
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year")
```

you can find the contents of M by:

```
> M
```

and you can find the plot on your browser:

```
> plot(M)
```

then, what is necessary to generate the chart is M$html$chart:

```
> M$html$chart
[1] "<!-- MotionChart ... omitted... \">\n</div>\n"
```

save it to a file:

```
> cat(M$html$chart, file="tmp.html")
```

if you open the "tmp.html" as a file (i.e, address says files:///***/tmp.html), then security warning may occur. What you need is to access the html via http://.

So if you can edit any web page where <script> tag is available (e.g., blogger), you can use it by simply copy and paste the contents of tmp.html, like this:

http://takahashik.blogspot.com/2011/01/googlevis-example.html

here is the famous "iris" version of example:

http://takahashik.blogspot.com/2011/01/googlevis-example-for-data-iris_10.html

Otherwise, if you have a web server, you can use it by uploading the tmp.html on the server.

Comment: You were right! It worked for me too! Could you supplement your tutorial showing the way to create a chart where the data will be generated dynamically (e.g. by querying a database using RODBC)??

Comment: Hi, sounds good. Could you please tell what you mean by "dynamically"? Do you mean that just getting data and generate googleVis output on R, or anything else?

Comment: I mean that perhaps we could mix html and R code to create content on the fly (I am interested in the web site solution again). Paragraph 1.2 of package vignette says "The charting data can either be embedded into the html file or read dynamically". Then in 2.5 mentions that again (in conjunction with the R.rsp package). I think that this would be great.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Then I will play with them. If I get them, I will post here or anywhere else.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make the stuff work with file:// protocol? I don't get any warnings. It just don't work:(. Security settings?

Comment: Solved!, it was flash security which should have been changed [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to  copy and paste the chart manually to a CMS (e.g. Joomla/Wordpress site), than you could do it from the 'gvis' object's html list. Just like @kohske suggested:

```
# demo data from manual
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year")
# write the HTML body to a temporary file without header and footer
cat(M$html$chart, file="temp.html")
# or with caption included:
cat(paste(M$html[c("chart", "caption")], collapse="\n"), file="temp.html")
```

Then copy and paste the content of temp.html to your Joomla site. You should pay attention to paste the code as HTML content, not in the WYSIWYG editor (e.g. Tiny MCE)!

If you want to show it on a separate page, do not forget to include header and footer also:

```
# demo data from manual
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year")
# write the HTML to a temporary file with header and footer all included
cat(paste(M$html, collapse="\n"), file="temp.html")
```

And at last: you can easily upload this document to e.g. an ftp server and reach it via any browser.

Comment: And of course you could open this (latter) temp.html file on local machine without a webserver also, thanks for @ViroshKa for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

Flash content might not work on local machine. I had to change the security restrictions on [adobe site](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) in order to make it work.

Now, by following daroczig's instructions one can view the content in the local browser and do not rely on R.rsp altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively write the following code

```
print(M,"chart", file="myfile")
```

copy and paste the html output to your webpage and the googleVis chart will run

Comment: This didn't work for me. `myfile.html` renders a blank page in chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script to run automatically as data updates and place a googleVis chart on a website using RCurl and googleVis. Here is an example where visChart is the chart:

```
library(RCurl)
library(googleVis)
```

make visChart

```
write(visChart$html$chart, file='visChart.html')
ftpUpload('visChart.html', "ftp://username:password@example.com/path/to/'visChart.html")
```

`visChart$html$chart` gives just the html for just the chart with out the footer so then I use an iframe in my HTML to access this chart. If you are using a google site, blogger or want a google gadget you can use createGoogleGadget():

```
write(createGoogleGadget(visChart), file='visChart.xml')
ftpUpload('visChart.xml', "ftp://username:password@example.com/path/to/'visChart.xml")
```