# default variables for a googleVis MotionChart

Tags: r, google-visualization

I am trying to create a `googleVis MotionChart` with the Google Visualization API, using the `R` package.

My problem is that I would like to publish the MotionChart on the internet and for this I want to be able to control the default variables for the different axis/dimensions.

A lot of information can be set using:

```
gvisMotionChart(M, options=list(state='xxx')
```

Where `'xxx'` is the state which can be copied from the Advanced tab in a MotionChart, however the default time series are not included in the state.

My question is, how can I choose the default variables for the different axis/dimensions of the googleVis MotionChart?

Comment: There have been answers to similar questions in the past:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063410/r-googlevis-problem-embedding-on-blogger
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646779/embedding-googlevis-charts-into-a-web-site

Comment: Thanks for the links DWin, but I can't really see anything on the default variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a little interface function to gvisMotionChart that allows to specify default values for xvar,yvar, colorvar and sizevar in addition to idvar and timevar. It accomplishes this by simply changing the column order of the provided data.frame. The function also transforms booleans into numbers (otherwise gvisMotionChart throws an error). Since I the motion chart also quite convenient for analyzing cross sectional data, it allows to set timevar=NULL.

```
    # Convenience interface to gvisMotionChart that allows to set default columns
    myMotionChart = function(df,idvar=colnames(df)[1],timevar=colnames(df)[2],xvar=colnames(df)[3],yvar=colnames(df)[4], colorvar=colnames(df)[5], sizevar = colnames(df)[6],...) {
        library(googleVis)

        # Generate a constant variable as column for time if not provided
        # Unfortunately the motion plot still shows 1900...
        if (is.null(timevar)) {
            .TIME.VAR = rep(0,NROW(df))
            df = cbind(df,.TIME.VAR)
            timevar=".TIME.VAR"
        }

        # Transform booleans into 0 and 1 since otherwise an error will be thrown
        for (i in  1:NCOL(df)) {
            if (is.logical(df [,i])[1])
                df[,i] = df[,i]*1
        }

        # Rearrange columns in order to have the desired default values for
        # xvar, yvar, colorvar and sizevar
        firstcols = c(idvar,timevar,xvar,yvar,colorvar,sizevar)
        colorder = c(firstcols, setdiff(colnames(df),firstcols))
        df = df[,colorder]

        gvisMotionChart(df,idvar=idvar,timevar=timevar,...)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to do this programmatically in the googleVis package though I suspect a close reading of [Section 2.6 of the googleVis vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf) will give you a lead.

When I did this, I edited by hand. My own example of a [motion chart with European public health time series](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77053/motionchart/newdata.html) has some default time series chosen. Have a look at the source to that page, towards the very bottom. Tell us if this helps...

Comment: thanks! I did check ou the section 2.6, but I can't see how I can set any default variables for the axis there. I think my question might be a bit unclear, I'll rephrase.

Comment: I greatly liked your example @gauden. Looks like it deserves in-depth study of the policy implications as well as being a great R example.

Comment: Thanks @DWin. I used a combination of R for the visualisation and Python for the data wrangling and then a little hand coding. I am working on more depth and more of the same, but that is very encouraging.

Comment: @gauden
Many thanks for your example. I'd highly appreciate if I could get an access to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've figured out a workaround but it's kind of an annoying one. It seems the package passes the variables in the sequence in which they are in the dataset.

Therefore, in order to choose the default variables for the different axis/dimensions you have to change the order of the variables in the dataframe. The order in which variables are assigned to axis is as follows:

1. X-axis
2. Y-axis
3. Dot colour
4. Dot size

The ID (e.g. country) and time (e.g. year) variables are automatically recognised. Meaning that the first variables after these two, will be put on the X-axis, the second on the Y-axis, etc.

However, there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a better way, but when I did something similar recently, I think I found the default order of the variables to be:

```
## order of variables in data file:
##  1 = idvar
##  2 = timevar
##  3 = bubble colour
##  4 = x var
##  5 = y var
##  6 = bubble size
```

The example uses World Bank data:

```
library(googleVis)
library(WDI)

HealthWealth = WDI(country="all", indicator=c("SP.DYN.LE00.IN", "NY.GDP.PCAP.CD", "SP.POP.TOTL"),
   start = 1960, end = 2010, extra = TRUE)  #Can take some time
HealthWealth = HealthWealth[-which(is.na(HealthWealth$Country.Name)), ]
HealthWealth = HealthWealth[-which(HealthWealth$Region == "Republic of Belarus"),]
HealthWealth = HealthWealth[, c(37, 3, 10, 5,4,6)]
names(HealthWealth) = c("Country", "Year", "Region", "GDP.(Current.$US)", "Life.Expectancy", "Population")
## order of variables in data file:
##  1 = idvar
##  2 = timevar
##  3 = bubble colour
##  4 = x var
##  5 = y var
##  6 = bubble size

## Create a motion chart
M <- gvisMotionChart(HealthWealth, idvar="Country", timevar="Year")  # Be patient

## Display the chart in your browser
plot(M)   # Change the x axis from lin to log
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also what I have now (actually also using WB data). But I would still like to know how to change it without changing the order of the variables.