# Converting special characters to utf-8 in googleVis charts

Tags: php, html, r, special-characters, google-visualization

In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646779/embedding-googlevis-charts-into-a-web-site) an html (or php) file is produced and a googleVis chart can then be loaded into a joomla (for example) article, using something like that

```
{source}
<?php
  include("tmp.php");
?>
{/source}
```

The column name with the subject to be analysed must be passed to the [gvisMotionChart's](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/googleVis/html/gvisMotionChart.html) idvar property. In my case this column includes values in greek and they appear as squares on the chart. I thought I could use [iconv](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert those strings to utf-8 character encoding. However, I haven't been able to use it successfully.

Could you help me have those labels shown properly?

**EDIT**

I found out that if I replace the strings including greek characters (the double quotes included) as follows, then it works

Replace

```
"greekcharacters"
```

with

```
<?php echo '"' . iconv('greek','utf-8','greekcharacters') . '"'; ?>
```

How can I do this globally, within R?

Comment: Squares in the output is usually a sign of a *font* problem, not an encoding problem. I.e. the font used does not contain that character. An encoding problem usually manifests itself in unintended characters instead. Just a wild stab in the dark though.

Comment: @deceze When I select View-Encoding-Greek(Windows) in IE, I can see the characters correctly (but of course everything else in the page is now unreadable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found it. Instead of

```
cat(M$html$chart, file="tmp.php")
```

use

```
cat(M$html$chart, file = (con <- file("tmp.php", "w", encoding="UTF-8"))); close(con)
```

I found it at the end of the [connections](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/base/html/connections.html) help file