# Unable to display googleVisMotion chart in Wordpress,Rpubs & Rmd file

Tags: r, wordpress, googlevis

I am unable to display googleVisMotion Chart in Wordpress,RPubs or as RMarkdown. The googleVisMotion Chart works locally on my computer but I am unable to get it to display anywhere else. I tried the method in post

[Embedding googleVis charts into a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646779/embedding-googlevis-charts-into-a-web-site?rq=1)

But that did not work for Wordpress when I paste the file in HTML page. When I tried to publish in RPubs using Rmd I just get

```
   "## starting httpd help server ..."
```

and no chart.

Please let me know how I can display the googleVisMotion chart? Are there other methods?

Comment: It works with knitr. Markus has some examples on his blog. http://www.magesblog.com/2012/10/googlevis-032-is-released-better.html You can do knitrRmd  to Rmd. I don't know anything specific to Wordpress, but you can always put custom HTML in WP with the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the chart as a html as suggested in [Embedding googleVis charts into a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646779/embedding-googlevis-charts-into-a-web-site?rq=1). I then hosted the Html page as a Github page (gh-pages) and this worked.